# running bitcoin-qt so it loads data from a local testnet (just 2 nodes on my own pc)

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I'm running a local tesnet from [freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box](https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box), which I built and ran locally (through docker*), with the command:

```
docker run -ti --name btcdev -P -p 49020:19000 bitcoin-testnet-box
```

which was inspired by the advice of [this issue on github](https://github.com/c0achmcguirk/docker-bitcoin-abe/issues/1#issuecomment-228248401), anyway- here how it looked:

```
bitcoin-dev-box, and mapping it's internal port 19000 to your localhost:49020
$ docker run -ti --name btcdev -P -p 49020:19000 poliver/bitcoin-dev-box
```

the advice on why to run it that way goes as follows:

```
The connect parameter is the server address. 
If you leave it blank it will connect to the bitcoin network directly. 
In the case above it's going to connect to your bitcoin testnet running inside the docker container. 
It's connecting to localhost:49020 which should be talking to the network inside the docker container if you mapped it to that port when you started bitcoin-dev-box.
```

then I ran bitcoin-qt with the command:

```
# Running bitcoin-dev-box, and mapping it's internal port 19000 to your localhost:49020
$ docker run -ti --name btcdev -P -p 49020:19000 poliver/bitcoin-dev-box
```

but still it seems that it's not connecting to my local testnet, here's a screenshot

**bitcoin-qt**:

[image: sss]

**output of 'docker ps'**:

[image: zzz]

alright- so- here comes the quesetion

**QUESTION**:
how can I configure bitcoin-qt, or another wallet- such that it will load only the data from my local testnet, just two nodes, on my own machine, that looks something like this:

```
bitcoin-cli -datadir=1  getinfo
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 0.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1413617762,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
bitcoin-cli -datadir=2  getinfo
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 0.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1413617762,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

*so that I could set the ip address myself- is there a way to do that while running it locally without using docker?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to run bitcoin-qt with the testnet-box is
make start-gui